# google chrome say thinks my site is malware

Tags: google-chrome

when i want ope my domain by google chrome i get error like this:

> The site ahead contains malware
>
> Attackers currently on MYSITE.com might attempt to install
>   dangerous programs on your computer that steal or delete your
>   information (for example, photos, passwords, messages, and credit
>   cards).
>
> Automatically report details of possible security incidents to Google.
>   Privacy policy Back to safetyDetails

i cheek site there : http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=mydomine:

> Safe Browsing Diagnostic page for MYSITE
>
> What is the current listing status for  MYSITE Site is listed
>   as suspicious - visiting this web site may harm your computer.
>
> What happened when Google visited this site? Of the 7 pages we tested
>   on the site over the past 90 days, 1 page(s) resulted in malicious
>   software being downloaded and installed without user consent. The last
>   time Google visited this site was on 2015-01-12, and the last time
>   suspicious content was found on this site was on 2015-01-12. This site
>   was hosted on 1 network(s) including AS28751 (CAUCASUS-NET-AS).
>
> Has this site acted as an intermediary resulting in further
>   distribution of malware? Over the past 90 days,  MYSITE did not
>   appear to function as an intermediary for the infection of any sites.
>
> Has this site hosted malware? No, this site has not hosted malicious
>   software over the past 90 days.
>
> How did this happen? In some cases, third parties can add malicious
>   code to legitimate sites, which would cause us to show the warning
>   message.
>
> Next steps: Return to the previous page. If you are the owner of this
>   web site, you can request a review of your site using Google Webmaster
>   Tools. More information about the review process is available in
>   Google's Webmaster Help Center.

in ftp  i delete all file , there is nothing now. 
but in google chrome  i cannot ope domne,  how  Correct this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you're certain your site is free of malware, you can ask Google to review it  [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/168328?hl=en)